# Cannot attach a file as database in child solution of partitioned solutions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I recently started working on partitioned solutions using `MVC 4` I set up my solution using [Structuring Solutions and Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817674.aspx) and [Adding an existing Visual Studio solution to another solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/06/24/walkthrough-adding-an-existing-visual-studio-solution-to-another-solution.aspx). My System is all set up, can build and i have enable migrations on both solutions. Each solution has 4 projects (Domain, Data, UnitTests and WebUI), the child solution has references from master solution. the data layer contains all the repositories and DbContext classes. And each solution has its own connection string, hence i intend to have separate databases for each of the solutions added to the system.

I was trying to update my databases in the `Package Manager Console` using `Update Database -Verbose` This worked for the master solution but has not worked with the child solution. Migration files are in the Data layer.

Note: I run `Update-Database -Verbose`

`Using StartUp project Master.WebUI and
Using NuGet project Master.Data` (Master Solution)

`Using StartUp project Child.WebUI and
Using NuGet project Child.Data` (Child Solution)

What should i do to make this work?

Comment: I didn't quite solve this, but what i did was recreate the `Child solution` and make the first `Updat-Database` before adding it to `Master Solution`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I could't solve this, so what i did was recreate the `Child solution` and make the first `Updat-Database` before adding it to `Master Solution`.

Now, i think it was just a matter of checking to make sure that the `Database` does not exist anywhere else. So deleting your `database` from `App_Data`, `Server Explorer`, `SQL Server Object Explorer` would work in an case when an `.mdf file cannot be attached as a database`

Comment: My problem is that App_Data is empty and I still get that annoying error